# function loops even though it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

With this function i want to insert data into my firebase database:

```
function insertDaten(titel) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
        var json_elemente = snapshot.val().notes;
        var keys = Object.keys(json_elemente);
        var count = Math.max.apply(null, keys) + 1;

        firebase.database().ref("notes/" + count).set({
            id: parseInt(count) + 1,
            text: "",
            titel: titel,
            bild: ""
    });
  });
}
```

but everytime i run it, it seems to loop and create as many datasets as it can before the program shuts down.
i've tried to just add a return; but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Did you mean to do `.once` instead of `.on`?

Comment: .on("value", cb) would essentially assign a callback to be executed once there is data in that ref. So, that creates an infinite loop, since you are writing inside the listening callback.

Comment: Both comments sounds like the start of a great answer folks. :-D

Comment: looks like you're listening for changes, but then making the changes in a loop, so it's infinite